# How to finalize the scroll class change?

Tags: javascript, html

class change at li
when li gets into the viewport - there is a class change

`enter code here` https://jsfiddle.net/2b5Lqfcd/

Comment: Use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this.

Comment: ie need......................

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener that listens for scroll and when event happens you can add the class you want to add